# Allow users to add items to JQuery autocomplete with categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using JQuery autocomplete with categories to let users choose one item from a list.

What I'd like to do now is to allow users to add a new item to one of the two available categories.

This is what I have now:

HTML:

```
<input id="procura"></input>
```

JS:

```
$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
        var that = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            that._renderItemData(ul, item);
        });
    }
});

$(function () {
    var data = [{
        label: "Vendas",
        category: "Recebimentos"
    }, {
        label: "Serviços",
        category: "Recebimentos"
    }, {
        label: "Outros",
        category: "Recebimentos"
    }, {
        label: "Fornecedores",
        category: "Pagamentos"
    }, {
        label: "FSW",
        category: "Pagamentos"
    }, {
        label: "Outros",
        category: "Pagamentos"
    }];

    $("#procura").catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: data
    });
});
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/E9eWa/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add inputs to collect the new item to be added to the dropdown, as well as the category to which it should be added. Then, simply push the new item to the data array.

The code below has been extended based on what you provided, although you'll need to add to it so the user can choose a category:

HTML:

```
<input id="procura"></input>
<br>
New Item:
<input id="new_item"></input><button onclick="add_item();">Add</button>
```

JS:

```
$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
_renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
    var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
    $.each(items, function (index, item) {
        if (item.category != currentCategory) {
            ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
            currentCategory = item.category;
        }
        that._renderItemData(ul, item);
    });
}
});

var data = [{
    label: "Vendas",
    category: "Recebimentos"
}, {
    label: "Serviços",
    category: "Recebimentos"
}, {
    label: "Outros",
    category: "Recebimentos"
}, {
    label: "Fornecedores",
    category: "Pagamentos"
}, {
    label: "FSW",
    category: "Pagamentos"
}, {
    label: "Outros",
    category: "Pagamentos"
}];

function add_item()
{
    var add_to_list = {};
    add_to_list['label'] = $('#new_item').val();;
    add_to_list['category'] = "Recebimentos"; // ADD INPUT TO CHOOSE
    data.push(add_to_list);
    $('#new_item').val('');
}

$(function () {

    $("#procura").catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: data
    });
});
```

See jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/E9eWa/10/

This answer also provides similar insight: [Adding values to jQuery autocomplete real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984614/adding-values-to-jquery-autocomplete-real-time)