# Autocomplete jquery two fields based on the first field value needs to populate as autocomplete in second field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have two text fields with id and name using jquery documentation I have succesfully achieved autocomplete for first text box now I am trying when the user type the value in first text field the relevant sub products needs to be shown second field as autocomplete.

Here Is my HTML code for auto complete

```
<input type="text" id="Product" name="Product"/>

<input type="text" id="subProduct" name="subProduct"/>
```

Jquery code for the current one

```
$(function() {
var availableItem = [
    "Fruits",
    "Vegetables",
    "Accesories"
];
var availableItem1 = [
    "Apple",
    "Strawberies",
    "Grapes"
];
 var availableItem2 = [
    "Potato",
    "LadiesFinger",
    "BitterGuard"
];
var availableItem3 = [
    "Headset",
    "Mouse",
    "Keyboard"
];  
  $("#Product").autocomplete({
    source:availableItem
  });
  $("#subProduct").autocomplete({
    source:availableItem
 });
});
```

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/1h23nvnf/)

Kindly suggest me how do this

Comment: you want to append values ??

Comment: @Muhammad how to append based on the select value

Comment: check the answer please

Answer (score 1):

Bind function to your first input box as the code described.
This will work

```
$("#Product").on('input change keyup autocompletechange',function(){
    if(availableItem.indexOf($("#Product").val()) != -1){
        $("#subProduct").autocomplete({
            source:eval('availableItem'+(availableItem.indexOf($("#Product").val())+1).toString())
        });
    }
});
```

See fiddle
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/vxb8uxqb/3/)

Comment: If you do not want to use eval you must define your source for other elements in a object

Comment: thanks for your effort is that possible can we do the same using JSON data

Comment: Yes, in case of Json you can explicitily define keys in an object mapping to the array of corresponding category elements, which will replace the overhead of eval function simply access the value corresponding to key defined by first input value.

Comment: can you please provide example it will be usefull for me thanks in advance

Comment: I have convereted your array of subitems to an object like this 

`var availableSubItems = {'Fruits':[

        "Apple",
        "Strawberies",
        "Grapes"
    ],
'Vegetables':[
        "Potato",
        "LadiesFinger",
        "BitterGuard"
    ],
'Accesories':[
        "Headset",
        "Mouse",
        "Keyboard"
    ]};)`


Also to view working code see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxb8uxqb/4/)

I hope this will work

Comment: Hi @Ankit can you please update in the jsfiddle and can you please tell my why updated to an object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88072/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-ankit-agarwal).

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution already given on [StackoverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984614/adding-values-to-jquery-autocomplete-real-time) that will show how to append values on changings.

Comment: not like that one I want the subproducts needs to dynamically generate in the second field as a autocomplete

Comment: @Mahadevan I have updated you Fiddle may this will help you http://jsfiddle.net/1h23nvnf/1/