# Adding values to jQuery autocomplete real time 'web service'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How to do the same solution used in this link [Adding values to jQuery autocomplete real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984614/adding-values-to-jquery-autocomplete-real-time)

but using a web service instead of array as a source

This is My code:

```
$("#Agent").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#Agent").data("agentlist-url"),
            data: "prefix=" + request.term,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.ID + ' - ' + item.NAME,
                        value: item.ID,
                        Type: item.TYPE,
                    };
                }));
            },
        });
    },
    select: function (e, i) {
        $("#Agent_Id").val(i.item ? i.item.Id : "");
        $("#Agent_Name").val(i.item.Name);
        $("#Agent_Type").val(i.item.Type);
    },
    change: function (ev, ui) {

    },
});
```

For example, if the available types are ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"]. The user types in "plums," when using the text field. Is there a way to add "plums" to the list of sources if the user so desires?

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to fetch the data needed and then insert it into jQuery UI autocomplete

```
$.get("url for web service").done(function(data) {
    // Assuming data returns as an array, if not - convert it to one.
  $("#auto-complete-input").autocomplete({
    source: data
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ajax to call your web service. See an example on the
[link](http://codehandbook.org/call-web-service-from-jquery-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You need two web services:

- One that accepts a search term and returns an array of strings that contain the search term (or an empty array if no results met the search term).
  (e.g. `yourdomain/words/search?term={yoursearchterm}`)
- One that accepts a string to add in your list of possible values, so that value can be return in the next search
  (e.g. `yourdomain/words/add`)

You could call your web service which returns results like this:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
       $.ajax({
           url: "yourdomain/words/search",
           data: request.term, 
           type: "GET",  // This will depend on how you set up your web service
           dataType: "json", 
           success: function (data) { 
              response($.map(data.d, function (item) { 
                  return { 
                      label: item.Name + '(' + item.Value + ')', 
                      value: item.Name 
                  } 
              })) 
           } 
       });
    },
});
```

In the example you linked to, [the accepted answer](http://jsfiddle.net/rmGqB/) shows a button when the input was not in autocomplete dropdown list (returned by your web service, in this case). You can change the function called by that button's `onClick` event to call your second web service, passing the value of your autocomplete input field. You can modify it as follows:

```
$("#add").on("click", function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $.ajax({
       url: "yourdomain/words/add",
       data: $("#auto"), 
       type: "POST",  // This will depend on how you set up your web service
       success: function () { 
          console.log('Word added');
       } 
   });
});
```

Comment: Yes I have the two services, My question is how to show and hide the Add button?